# Error when creating linked server in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When I create a linked server in SQL Server, it causes an error

> Cannot create a instance of OLEDB provider SQLNCLI10 for linked server 'linked server name '(microsoft sql server error 7302)

How can I rectify this error?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2555855

Answer (score 1):

The OLEDB provider may not properly installed. What you chose is the SQL Server native client. Do you have SSMS installed on server? This should come with sql native client OLE DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share an experience when I faced following error

> Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "xxx.YYYY" for linked server "test". Error 7302.

I observed this message from a failed SQL Server job. On analysis it is found that `Allow Inprocess` was not enabled for the `provider`. When this is enabled, everything worked fine for me.

**Server Objects --> Linked Servers --> Providers**

Also refer following

1. ["Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider" error as Windows Authentication user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499977/cannot-create-an-instance-of-ole-db-provider-error-as-windows-authentication-u)
2. [Linked Server Properties (Provider Options Page)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188095(v=sql.105).aspx)
3. [Configuring OLE DB Providers for Distributed Queries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190918(v=sql.105).aspx)