# OPENROWSET From SQL to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, openrowset, oraoledb

i'm trying to connect from sql server to oracle server with OPENROWSET for fetch data.

this is my query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET(N'OraOLEDB.Oracle', N'Data Source=Myip:Port/dbname';'User Id=user';'Password=pass;',
   'select *   FROM  view  WHERE value = ''102030'' ') AS a;
```

sql return below error:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "(null)" returned
>   message "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier
>   specified". Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 23 Cannot initialize the
>   data source object of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked
>   server "(null)".

how can i fix this ?

I used Linked Server for fetch data but oracle table not small and it takes a long time to execute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499977/cannot-create-an-instance-of-ole-db-provider-error-as-windows-authentication-u

Comment: thanks , i checked it but the problem still exists.

Comment: Test connection for linked server, check this: https://dbafox.com/openrowset-query-oracle-sql-server-using-linked-server/